# How do I successfully delete an item from keychain in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, keychain

How do I successfully delete an item from keychain in OS X? This is what I have so far, but it is failing at the `SecItemDelete` call. Do I need to specify some additional attributes in the query dictionary or something? I can successfully insert key-value pairs into the keychain by doing similar operations.

```
#define DELETE_SIZE 3
bool delete_key_keychain( const char *cKeyValue, SecKeychainRef keychain) {
    if ( !keychain)
        return false;

    // Convert to CFString.
    CFStringRef keyValue = CFStringCreateWithCString( NULL, cKeyValue, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    if ( !keyValue)
        return false;

    // Specify query parameters.
    const void *keys[DELETE_SIZE] = {
        kSecClass,
        kSecUseKeychain,
        kSecAttrAccount
    };
    const void *values[DELETE_SIZE] = {
        kSecClassGenericPassword,
        keychain,
        keyValue
    };

    // Create query.
    CFDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreate( NULL, keys, values, GET_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
    if ( !query) {
        CFRelease( keyValue);
        return false;
    }

    // Run query.
    OSStatus status = SecItemDelete( query);
    CFRelease( query);
    CFRelease( keyValue);

    return status == errSecSuccess;
}
```

Update: According to this [link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/28/keychain-duplicate-item-when-adding-password.html), I need to set the `kSecAttrService` property in the query. As a result, I started using `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword` and `SecKeychainItemDelete`. This will delete the password successfully, however subsequently adding a different password for the same account can cause crashes. Therefore, I've started using `SecKeychainItemModifyAttributesAndData` to modify the password and don't delete passwords. I believe this instability might be due to caching that the API performs.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, i've used this function for delete a specific public/private keypair items from my Mac OS keychain

```
// remove keypair from keychain
- (BOOL)deleteKeysFromKeychain {
    OSStatus sanityCheck1 = noErr;
    OSStatus sanityCheck2 = noErr;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary * queryPrivateKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:self.myPublicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    // Set the private key query dictionary.
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:self.myPrivateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    // Delete the private key.
    sanityCheck1 = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPrivateKey);

    // Delete the public key.
    sanityCheck2 = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey);

    @autoreleasepool {
        queryPrivateKey = nil;
        queryPublicKey = nil;
    }

    return ( sanityCheck1 == sanityCheck2  && sanityCheck2 == noErr ? YES : NO );    
}
```

Where myPublicTag is something like **'com.yourAppName.publickey'**

Where myPrivateTag is something like **'com.yourAppName.privatekey'**

Maybe this could be useful

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turned out the problem was that I did not set the `kSecAttrService` property in my query.